Why is wristwatch in Chinese called 手表?
As a native French speaker studying Mandarin Chinese, I couldn't help but notice that the Chinese term for wristwatch, 手表 (hand-show), is quite similar to the French term "une montre" (a "shower"/display). After further inspection, I notice that other European languages' term are quite different. All of Spanish, Portuguese and German have a term that translates roughly to "arm clock" and English it's "watch".
Is the term 手表 actually originated from French or is it a pure coincidence? Was it French who introduced wristwatches to China, and if so, why France and not Chinese colonizers such as the United Kingdom or Portugal?

I mean... English "watch" is very similar too, just from an active point of view of the person watching rather than a passive point of view of the thing being displayed. And "wristwatch" itself seems very similar to "hand-show".

表 biǎo is short for 钟表 zhōngbiǎo ‘watch’, where the first character more unambiguously means ‘clock, bell’ (those two are the same words in several European languages as well). I don’t know whether the use of this particular character/word to refer to watches was influenced by European languages, but it’s also used for various other instruments that show or display things: 水表 shuǐbiǎo ‘water meter’, 温度表/体温表 wēndùbiǎo/tǐwēnbiǎo ‘thermometer’, 仪表 yíbiǎo ‘instrument, gauge’, so it’s quite a logical word to use even without any Western influence.

Fantastic. This good question is asked by a new contributor; and its good and accepted answer as well as the other answers on it are all provided by new contributors!

Posted from History.SE: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/76972/8066

Each character in Chinese can mean many different things. In this context, your translation of 表 as "show" is not correct. (For example, 表哥 does not translate as "show elder brother".)
Here with 手表, 表 was originally from 圭表, which was a sort of ancient sundial for telling the seasons.
And in 圭表, 表 referred to the gnomon:

An object such as a pillar or a rod that is used to tell time by the shadow it casts when the sun shines on it, especially the pointer on a sundial.

Today, 表 can refer to any measurement device, hence also 电表 (electricity meter), 水表 (water meter), 钟表 ("bell meter"--or clock or watch), and 手表 ("hand meter"--or watch).
https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%A1%A8/

The word "手表" is indeed composed of "手" and "表", and its surface meaning is "the watch on the hand". In Chinese, "表" generally refers to a timer or data display, similar to the French word "montre". The similarity between these two words may be a coincidence or due to the influence of French language and culture on some cultural and technological fields in China during certain historical periods, especially from the late Ming Dynasty to the fall of the Qing Dynasty.
Regarding the introduction of watches, the history of watches is as complex as their construction. The earliest pocket watches developed in Europe, especially in the UK and Switzerland. As a portable timekeeping tool, watches first became popular in the late 19th and early 20th centuries.
The introduction of watches in China is indeed closely related to Western contacts, which cannot be ignored. From the mid-19th century to the early 20th century, with the two Opium Wars and a series of other events, China's exchanges with Western countries increased, and Western technology and culture gradually entered China. During this period, the cultural influence of France was relatively significant, especially in some coastal cities such as Shanghai and Guangzhou, where many French businessmen and cultural figures settled and developed. Naturally, the habits, culture, and cuisine represented by some individuals will interact and have an impact on the local culture.
Regarding the second question, as for why it is "手表" instead of a term from other countries, it may be due to French having been more popular in certain specific periods and fields.
The formation of the word "watch" may be the result of multiple factors working together, rather than just the influence of a certain country.
